# Center alignment without the need for height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Seen a few tutorials and doc now. Where its claimed,

all you need to do is the following to both horizontally and vertically align a div.

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
```

But is not true from what I see. It aligns horizontally but not vertically.

For it to align it vertically, you need to add `height`.

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 500px;
}
```

But this is not being dynamic for it to always stay center for any height.
`height: 100%` doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong, or the docs / tutorials are incorrect?

Trying this on `Edge browser` if it matters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <style>

        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .grid {
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <article class="grid">
            <div>
                
            </div>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Doc and tutorial references:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/njdJeu95p6s

https://youtu.be/qm0IfG1GyZU?t=128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't set `height` to the parent element.

You can use `height: 100%;`, but then you also need to set `height` to the parent element (i.e., `<body>` in your case).

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<style>
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid red;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <article class="grid">
    <div>
      
    </div>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. That does work. But still involves the need to mention height which is not addressed in the docs nor tutorials.

Comment: If you take a look at [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items), you can see that there's always `height` set (using [`display: flex;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items#placing_items_in_a_flex_container) or [`display: grid;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items#placing_items_in_a_grid_container)).

Answer (score 0):

You may like to look up the way that width is treated in a block element.

e.g. in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

> Note: A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up
> the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far
> as it can).

which is why your emoji centers horizontally.

The height is just the height of the content which is the emoji.

If you are trying to center the emoji in the middle of the viewport then give the element the height of the viewport. If you are trying to center it in its parent (which currently is the body element) then give it the height of the parent (height: 100%).

This snippet assumes you want it centered in the viewport:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<style>
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    place-items: center;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <article class="grid">
    <div>
      
    </div>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you set `margin: auto;` for that element it gets centered in the parent element. But it should not be overwritten by other positioning attributes, so I suggest you try doing this solution to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can not vertically in a section as the `section` by default does not have any extra height in it.

In the below code, you can see that if we apply `height` to the `.height` class then the `section` gets height.

> you can use `100vh` or `100%` or some height in pixels

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  background: #21977c69;
  place-items: center;
}

.grid>div {
  background: #fa977c69
}

.height {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <article class="grid">
    <div>
      
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="grid height">
    <div>
      this is a grid with a height
    </div>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```